# Java code to check HTTP headers for incoming request

Tags: java, ddos

I want to detect if there is any kind of vulnerable data present in the incoming request and only if the request headers looks okay it will taken by the server else it wil be deny by the server.

Also it would be if anybody could provide like to any opensource tools which already provide those.
I am doing this to minimise already existing DOS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a [javax.servlet.Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and configure it in the web.xml file (`<filter>` and `<filter-mapping>` tags). That will allow you to execute code on an incoming request to some (or all) your URLs and decide what to do, if normal processing, alternate processing, or simply nothing.

Just implement the `doFilter` method and if you want to let the request/response pair continue its processing, call `chain.doFilter(req, resp)`. Also you can provide request or response wrappers to the chain.